# Use tikz node `pos`-key on later reference to node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I want to use e.g. `\node[pos=0.8]{MYNODE};` after the node has been defined inside e.g. `\draw`:

Consider the following

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw(0,0) -- (2,2) node(myLine){};
        \node[above left,pos=0.8] at (myLine){Upper part};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which gives the following output

[image: Image showing that pos is "ignored"]

However, I would want it to present this output:

[image: Desired output (pos is not ignored)]

---

Desired output *could* be generated like the following, but the important part
is that the `pos` can be set later, not while drawing the node.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw(0,0) -- (2,2) node[pos=0.8](myLine){};
        \node[above left] at (myLine){Upper part};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks! :)

PS. Feel free to edit/clarify the title. I had a hard time formulating it.

Comment: `pos` can only be used in a meaningful way if you are in a path. So you may be looking for `\draw(0,0) -- (2,2) node[above left,pos=0.8] {Upper part};`.

Comment: It is also possible to set two or more nodes at a point: `\draw(0,0) -- (2,2) node[above left,pos=0.8]{Upper part}node(myLine){};`

Comment: @marmot Isn't that exactly what I'm clarifying in the last part of my answer that I don't want?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Maybe, however, it is just one command. It might well be that I do not understand your question, then.

Comment: @marmot This is just a minimal example. I basically want to make a tikz "interface" for a neural network figure code I wrote. I want to be able to connect to some lines in there at the pos-point of the line.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithms that place a node (coordinate, pic) along a path segment are called timers in the source code for TikZ (and the `pos`ition is called time internally, as well).

During the `--` path operation TikZ stores the start and the end point in two macros and sets the timer to be the one of the direct line. When a node with a `pos`ition is encountered this timer is then used which accesses the start/end point macros accordingly.

This does not survive the path or even the next path operation. We can hack something together, though:

Since the `\node` might be placed in a context that might not use the same transformation matrix as the `--` operation we'll just save these two points as coordinates and use them as start and end coordinates.

---

This is merely a proof-of-concept since we would need to write a saver and restorer for each timer (there are only four by default: `--`, `|-`/`-|`, `arc`, `.. controls ..`).

There is no good interface for this unfortunately.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  save line timer/.code=
    \pgfcoordinate{tikz@saved@timer@start@#1}{\tikz@timer@start}%
    \pgfcoordinate{tikz@saved@timer@end@#1}  {\tikz@timer@end},
  restore line timer/.code=
    \let\tikz@timer\tikz@timer@line
    \def\tikz@timer@start{\pgfpointanchor{tikz@saved@timer@start@#1}{center}}%
    \def\tikz@timer@end  {\pgfpointanchor{tikz@saved@timer@end@#1}  {center}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (2,2) [save line timer=myLine];
\tikzset{rotate=30, shift={(3,5)}} % random stuff
\node[restore line timer=myLine, above left, pos=.8] {Upper part};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```